# send keystroke to process

Tags: xorg, window, input, metacity

I'd like to run some applications in fullscreen. Even though they don't have an explicit such option, it is possible with the `metacity` Alt-F11 command.

So, I thought I could create such an input like this:

full.txt:

```
KeyStrPress Alt_L
KeyStrPress F11
KeyStrRelease F11
KeyStrRelease Alt_L
```

and then:

`xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < full.txt`
(in my case, the same as `xmacroplay :0.0 < full.txt`)

But, it works in the terminal where it is run. How do I send it to the `stdin` of some other process?

**Edit**: I found a better way to do this: `wmctrl -r urxvt -b toggle,fullscreen` (for urxvt). Check out my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783198) for (a bit) more on that.

Comment: Wouldn't sending something to `stdin` of some process require that process to read from `stdin`? What applications are you trying to run fullscreen? You are using GNOME I assume?

Comment: For example, `urxvt`, `emacs` and `iceweasel`. I am sort of using GNOME but I log in from `tty`, then `xinit` with `metacity` last in `.xinitrc`, so I guess a lot of the GNOME stuff is not there, but some might be. I got the Alt-F11 command from `metacity` and `gconf-editor`.

Comment: Sending keystrokes to metacity seems like a very roundabout way to make it perform an action. Doesn't metacity have a way to feed it commands?

Comment: I agree 100%, look at the command in my comment below, "roundabout" to say the least! But... `man metacity` is like one A4 and there is nothing there about commands. Do you know where else to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to focus the window that you want to recieve these keystrokes. `wmname` provides such functionality, you can probably find it in your package manager. `wmctrl -ai "$windowID" ; xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < full.txt` (where `$windowID` is the window ID as determined through `xwininfo`, et al) is probably what you want.

Comment: Yes, this works. It doesn't look very robust with the `sleep`, and it will not work if you have several instances, but I guess it is OK for applications you only start once at start up. `(emacs &) ; sleep 1 ; wmctrl -a emacs ; xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < full.txt 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null`

Comment: This: `wmctrl -r emacs -b toggle,fullscreen` is better, than what I wrote in my comment above.