# Start window in specific size and location, is there a general tool can do that?

Tags: x11, gui, window

Is there a general program, that start my GUI program, and able to specify the size and location of this program ? Not just X programs, but also other GUI libs.

Comment: You could also start the application, and then use `wmctrl` to set window size (see also [How to set window size and location of an application on screen via command line? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43106/how-to-set-window-size-and-location-of-an-application-on-screen-via-command-line)); however, you need a window ID to `wmctrl`, and I'm not sure what is the best way to get it non-interactively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Devil's Pie does have such an option. See e.g. [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) and [this howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=75749). In X11 parlance, a window's size and location make up its geometry. Write something like

```
(if (is (application_name) "Foo")
    (geometry "400x200-0+20"))
```