# xterm width and height with regard to number of pixels NOT number of characters

Tags: x11, fonts, xterm

On X window system (TWM) of my Ubuntu 12.04, xterm has width of **484** pixel and height of **316** pixel, and its geometry is 80x24, based on `xwininfo`.

On X window system (TWM) of my LFS 7.9, xterm has with of **644** pixel and height of **388** pixel, and its geometry is 80x24, based on `xwininfo`.

How can I configure xterm of LFS 7.9 so that its width by height size can be like Ubuntu 12.04? I like how Ubuntu xterm looks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An XTerm's size is determined by the number of characters its displaying, the font it is using, and the size of the window manager decorations (title bar, outlines, etc.).

You're probably using a different (larger) font on LFS. Ubuntu's xterm settings are probably in `/etc/X11/app-defaults/{XTerm,XTerm-color}` (at least that's where they are in Debian). You could copy them over, or at least the settings you want. [BTW: If you're not aware, XTerm has multiple fonts you can switch to via <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>RightClick</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Keypad +/-</kbd> (all bindings configurable).

You can also do that on a per-user basis in your `~/.Xresources` file and with `xrdb`.

If you want to know what all the settings in the XTerm app-defaults mean, the xterm manpage actually documents them thoroughly.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to translate from the xterm manpage to the `~/.Xresources` file or to the `app-defaults/XTerm` file? It's not clear to me how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianKeister that would probably be better asked as a new question, along with details (e.g., which settings in particular).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to resize and reposition my xterm terminal based on pixels as well. The solution I found was using [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43106/how-to-set-window-size-and-location-of-an-application-on-screen-via-command-line):

## Reposition and Resize using pixels

So what you do is when you're calling xterm, you provide a title to it for example:

```
xterm -T "My XTerm"
```

Then using xdotool you find the Window ID:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name "My XTerm"
```

You use the Window ID to set the size:

```
xdotool windowsize $WINDOW_ID_GOES_HERE $WIDTH $HEIGHT
```

And to reposition:

```
xdotool windowmove $WINDOW_ID_GOES_HERE $X $Y
```