# Spaces in tiling mode with urxvt in awesomewm

Tags: awesome, rxvt, x-resources

I use the terminal `urxvt` or `rxvt-unicode`, which feeds on `.Xresources`. This runs on an `archlinux` with `awesomewm`. I have the following `.Xresources` code:

```
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Xft settings
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Xft.dpi:                    96
Xft.antialias:              false
Xft.rgba:                   rgb
Xft.hinting:                true 
Xft.hintstyle:              hintslight

URxvt.dept10h:              32
URxvt.geometry:             100x25
URxvt.transparent:          false
URxvt.fading:               0
! URxvt.urgentOnBell:         true
! URxvt.visualBell:           true
URxvt.loginShell:           true
URxvt.saveLines:            500
URxvt.internalBorder:       20 ! DEFAULT = 3 
URxvt.lineSpace:            0 

! Fonts
URxvt.allow_bold:           true
URxvt*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Regular:pixelsize=12
URxvt*boldFont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold:pixelsize=13
URxvt*italicFont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Italic:pixelsize=13
URxvt*boldItalicFont: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold Italic:pixelsize=13
URxvt*letterSpace: 0 ! Fix font space

! Scrollbar
URxvt.scrollStyle:          rxvt
URxvt.scrollBar:            false

! Perl extensions
URxvt.perl-ext-common:      default,matcher,clipboard,selection-to-clipboard
URxvt.matcher.button:       1
URxvt.urlLauncher:          firefox
URxvt.matcher.rend.0: Uline Bold fg5

! Copy and paste
URxvt.clipboard.autocopy: true
URxvt.keysym.M-c: perl:clipboard:copy
URxvt.keysym.M-v: perl:clipboard:paste

! Cursor
URxvt.cursorBlink:          true
URxvt.cursorColor:          #657b83
URxvt.cursorUnderline:      false

! Pointer
URxvt.pointerBlank:         true


!!*fading: 40
*fadeColor: #002b36
*cursorColor: #93a1a1
*pointerColorBackground: #586e75
*pointerColorForeground: #93a1a1

URxvt*background: #151515
URxvt*foreground: #f7f7f7
!black
URxvt*color0: #101010
URxvt*color8: #404040
!red
URxvt*color1: #e5211d 
URxvt*color9: #ad3430 
!green
URxvt*color2: #77a026 
URxvt*color10: #94db43 
!yellow
URxvt*color3: #d2dd30 
URxvt*color11: #ddef56 
!blue
URxvt*color4: #2e97ba 
URxvt*color12: #77c6e5 
!magenta
URxvt*color5: #c42b7f 
URxvt*color13: #ef6bd5 
!cyan
URxvt*color6: #25b1c6 
URxvt*color14: #70e0ef 
!white
URxvt*color7: #dddddd
URxvt*color15: #ffffff
```

When I use the tiling mode on `awesomewm`, the terminal window appears leaving spaces in the bottom frame and the right frame.

[image]
[image]
[image]

To display the expected result I used `termite` in tiling mode (only take into account the window, not the transparencies or other topics):

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is why (in `.Xresources`) doesn't fill the entire screen in tiling mode like any other application. I specify it in the "expected result" with the `termite` example

Comment: That's because XTerm-like terminals determine their width/height from the characters width/height, not in pixels. So, unless the screen width is a multiple of the character width, there will be a gap on the right border. That's very sad, but some window managers let you fill that space, but I don't know about awesome, sorry.

Comment: This may be informative: [xterm width and height with regard to number of pixels NOT number of characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by adding the `c.size_hints_honor = false` line to the `client.connect_signal` method from `rc.lua` (`awesomewm` configuration file):

```lua
client.connect_signal("manage", function (c)
    c.size_hints_honor = false
    if awesome.startup
      and not c.size_hints.user_position
      and not c.size_hints.program_position then
        awful.placement.no_offscreen(c)
    end
end)
```

This way, the window manager ignores applications that use hints to define the size.

[image]