# XTerm: Scroll by pixels?

Tags: xterm, scrolling

In XTerm manual:

> **scroll-back(count [,units [,mouse] ])**
> This action scrolls the text window backward so that text that had
> previously scrolled off the top of the screen is now visible.
> The count argument indicates the number of units (which may be page,
> halfpage, pixel, or line) by which to scroll.
> (...)

It surprises me that the unit may be *pixel*. I use XTerm for a good amount
of time and never witnessed any pixel-aware behavior from it; rather, XTerm's
smallest unit of measure seems to be a *character*. (For example, [the possible
window sizes of XTerm are multiples of a character width/height](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277295). It won't
display 1/2 char, like other terminal emulators.)

So, I set off to the test and added these two entries in my `~/Xresources`:

```
XTerm*vt100.Translations: #override\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>k: scroll-back(1,pixel) \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>j: scroll-forw(1,pixel) \n\
```

After `xrdb ~/Xresources`, I opened a new XTerm and tried
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>,
but each scrolled only one line, not one pixel, which is the same
behavior of `scroll-{forw,back}(1,line)`.

Hence the question: What does *pixel* mean for the scroll action?
How is it different from *line*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably seems excessive, but the units have been supported for a long time (the [**`params_to_pixels`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d3bd1249f36040570d702aa0d030261ed79103cf/scrollbar.c#L654) function which implements this dates back to [X11R4](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/old-xterm/blob/aff055339109b8fe7bf146aecc340a622bae235e/scrollbar.c#L469) in 1988).  Likewise, the feature was documented in xterm's [manual page](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/old-xterm/blob/aff055339109b8fe7bf146aecc340a622bae235e/xterm.man#L1216) at that point.

The number (in pixels) is divided by the font-height when computing the amount by which to scroll.  Perhaps someone intended making it handle fractional rows (for smoother scrolling), but as implemented, it's "always" been lines.